# How can we auto magnify title bar upon cursor hover in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome-shell, titlebar

I have posted cursor hover auto magnification question previously but that is not related to title bar. Now what I want is to add this effect on the title bar. How can we do this?

I am already enjoying the auto-magnification of icons in the plank but just wish it were there for title bar as well. If someone knows how we can achieve this, please share.

[image: screenshot of title bar]

Thank you!!

Comment: I see your name associated with a lot of quesions about plank. Maybe yu should be looking into this web site https://answers.launchpad.net/plank/+questions

Comment: Thank you @David. I only found out about plank a couple of days back by a user who answered a question of auto-magnification on mouse hover. If the same features are put in the installation package directly, it would be very nice. :) Thank you for putting the link. :) However this question is not related to plank.